# foreach binding to an observable array is not working in knockoutjs when used inside a custom element attached using requirejs

Tags: knockout.js

In the below knockoutjs custom element (based on the example found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) ) the `foreach` does not loop through `myArray` and no output is produced, any help is highly appreciated.

Contents of `component-like-widget.js`

```
define(['path_to_knockoutjs/knockout'], function(ko) {
        function LikeWidgetViewModel(params) {
            this.myArray= ko.observableArray([
               { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
               { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
               { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }]);
        }

        return LikeWidgetViewModel;
    });
```

Contents of `component-like-widget.html`

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: myArray" >
        <a data-bind="text:$data.name">place holder2</a>
   </div>
```

the full example can be found [here](https://github.com/Saif-A/knockoutjs-custom-elements-example)

Comment: Did you call ko.applybinding?

Comment: sure, I have just added the git for the complete example.

Comment: I've moved your example into jsfiddle, and it all works: https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/2sb6jhj9/

Comment: please take a look at the git repo in the post. it happens when use it as a custom element attached using requirejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading two instances of Knockout. One Knockout instance won't recognize observables created in another instance. Change your component to use the global `ko` instead of loading its own.

```
define(function() {
  function LikeWidgetViewModel(params) {
....
```

Comment: thanks a lot, worked like charm. The documentation example itself has the same issue as found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/files/component-like-widget.js) . what was killing me is that it worked with normal observable but not with observable arrays.

Comment: This issue affects any observable created within the component viewmodel using the second Knockout instance. The other observable that your component is using was passed in and so doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Hopefully the docs can be fixed. https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2164

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the values. Remove it `return LikeWidgetViewModel;`

[Here is a sample link](https://jsfiddle.net/yLy5sL8r/)

Comment: everything works until you use it as a custom element. a full example is linked at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will observe inside `observableArray`:

```
this.myArray= ko.observableArray([
     { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
     { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
     { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }]);
}

// This is a trick inside ObserbableArray is not observable
for (var i = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++){
    this.myArray[i].name = ko.observable(this.myArray[i].name);
}
```